# Jersey @Path cannot process question mark('?')

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have two REST URLs like:

```
http://myschool/student/jack //get student information.
http://myschool/student/jack?books //get student books.
```

Code:

```
@Path("student")
public class StudentResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{name}")
    public Response getInformation(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return Response.ok(loadStudentInformation(name));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{name}?books") //ineffective expression
    public Response getBooks(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return Response.ok(loadStudentBooks(name));
    }
```

Jersey cannot process the second url 'http://myschool/student/jack?books', it always dispatch the incoming request which end with '?books' to the first method 'getInformation'.

I try to use regular expression like this:

```
    @GET
    @Path("{name : .*(\\?books$)}") //ineffective expression
    public Response getBooks(@PathParam("name") String studentName) {
```

The regular expression is ineffective too, can someone please help me figure out how to implement this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to use question mark to separate {name} and books, you can do it as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("{name}")
public Response getInformation(@PathParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("books") String books) {
    if (books != null) {
        // "books" was included after the question mark
        return getBooks(name);
    } else {
        // "books" was not included after the question mark
        return Response.ok(loadStudentInformation(name));
    }
}

public Response getBooks(String name) {
    return Response.ok(loadStudentBooks(name));
}
```

UPDATE: Also, if you are using a question mark where slash would be more appropriate (as according to the spec, question mark starts the query parameters section), as another alternative you can consider writing a ContainerRequestFilter that replaces question mark in the request by slash - this will allow you to design your resources as the other answer suggests without breaking the API compatibility.

The filter can be as simple as this:

```
public class QueryParamToPathSegmentFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        String requestUri = request.getRequestUri().toString();
        requestUri = requestUri.replace('?', '/');
        request.setUris(request.getBaseUri(), UriBuilder.fromUri(requestUri).build());
        return request;
    }

}
```

Depending on how your URI's look like - you can make it more sophisticated.
Here is more on how you can register filters in your application:
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I need a more graceful solution, because there are more than 40+ question mark style API, that means the if...else will be a big horrible. : )

Comment: So how about the solution involving the filter? I've updated my answer with an example of such filter that would map your "{name}?something" uri's to "{name}/something" uri's - that would allow you to use `@Path("{name}/something")` path templates on the resources and things would work as expected.

Comment: These REST-API use question mark as request dispatch, because the path parameter contains multi-slash, it could be 'books/english/19830001/abc.jpg' which contains multi-slash, so the filter will impact the path parameter.

Comment: As said, the filter can be more sophisticated - this is just to give you an idea. Basically you should think about how the right URI's should look like and use the filter to transform the old URI's to new ones. If the client is able to handle redirects, you may even want to send a redirect response with the right URI from the filter.

Comment: E.g. if you think the part that goes after the question mark should rather be at the beginning of your path, you can design it like that - i.e. the URI like "blabla/bookname/whatever?books" would be transformed to "books/blabla/bookname/whatever" - you can then have resource template like "books/{name: .*}" that would map to this URI and name would contain "blabla/bookname/whatever". Not sure if I correctly understood what you mean though.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the path to:

```
@Path("{name}/books")
```

instead of:

```
@Path("{name}?books")
```

and then you would just get the list of books at that url:

```
http://myschool/student/jack/books //get student books.
```

Question mark in a URL usually means that you want to pass parameters to a service (in which case you'd want to use `QueryParam`), but I don't think this is what it is about here, you just want to create a different service.

Comment: We are handling a legacy system and the REST APIs of which were already published, it cannot be changed, at present we cannot use Jersey(java rs) to handle this situation gracefully.